# Is this a security threat?

Tags: network-scanners

So at my business our receipt printer randomly printed some questionable looking data.

I looked into scanproxy.net and it's clearly not something legitimate.

Can anyone give me a better idea of what's happening here?

```
GET http://www.scanproxy.net:80/p-900.htm
1 HTTP/1.0
Content-Type: text/html
Proxy-Connection: keep-alive
Host: www.scanproxy.net
Accept: image/gif, image/x-xbitmap, image/jpeg, image/pjpeg, application/vnd.ms-powerpoint, application/vnd.ms-excel, application/msword, application/x-shockwave-flash */*
Accept-Language: en-us
User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; KuKu 0.65)
Authorization: Basic 0g==
```

All but one computer in the network are machines running OS:X - 1 Windows XP machine.

Customers sometimes connect to the network when they visit, so this might be such a situation.

What should be my next step?

Thanks so much!

Comment: Did you miss a step here? How did you get from "my printer did something weird", to scanproxy.net?

Comment: Wait, you allow customers to connect to the internet from your business computer?

Comment: Allow me to clarify. Customers have their own 'guest' network they connect to.

I didn't skip a step - the above is what the printer printed out.

Comment: Open proxy probing? That would be pretty random and on all your public IPs. One of these proxy scanners found your printer's IP, that would be my guess. What's its IP doing outside your firewall?

Comment: Your guess is as good as mine. its just a basic printer setup, it was not intentionally outside the network.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Anyone able to use your printer is a vulnerability.  This is a resource that should not be exposed to public networks.   I suspect that "scanproxy.net" is well... scanning for proxies.   Its likely that they connected to an open port and tried to proxy a GET request for `http://www.scanproxy.net:80/p-900.htm`,  but instead this was interpreted as data to be printed.

Conduct a full port scan (0-65535) of your network range from an external node. Close any unnecessary ports.